# Top visited entries on site collection blogs

Tags: list, web-part, javascript, visual-web-part, best-practices

I want to develop a web part which shows the ranking of entries of a site collection.

By now, I think a way to do this is to use a Javascript code added on the master page which adds a row to the statistic list (on the site collection) if the visitor visits a entry. Then, a webpart collected this information and shows the top 10.

Do you know another better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Most popular items is a native functionality in SharePoint:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2014/01/28/view-and-configure-usage-analytics-reports-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx#ViewMPI

Comment: That is for a specific List, such as Posts List in a Blog. I was talking about a ranking in the whole site collection.